# Is there any way to find response size instead of content length in python request response?

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask, python-requests

I have an endpoint that send requests to different urls and get the response and process it.

I have to get the response's size including the response headers and response body.

The requests library provides `calculate_content_length()` but I somehow feel both of them are not the same.

Thanks in Advance.

from flask import request, Response

```
resp = requests.get("https://someexamplesite.com/a/b, headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
wf_resp = Response(resp.content, headers=resp_headers, status=resp.status_code)
print(str(wf_resp.calculate_content_length()))
print(str(len('\r\n'.join('{}: {};'.format(k, v) for k, v in wf_resp.headers.items()))))
```

Output:
20342
1005
which totals to 21347 bytes

but in postman it shows different size (21.43KB):

[response_size_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP5gH.png)